# Default ContextMenu Style - WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu

I am trying to modify the default style of the ContextMenu in WPF.

Normally you can creat a copy of the default in Expression Blend using the Edit Control Parts (Template) > Edit a Copy menu option.  However I can't work out how to do this with a ContextMenu.  Any idea how I can get the default style to modify?

I am trying to disable the left side of the context menu where the icons are normally shown.

Thanks!

**Update:**  Maybe I wasn't clear about removing the icons.  For example, if you have a context menu with no icons then the whole left side of the menu is wasted space.  I would like to modify the default style of the context menu background to remove this.  Simply I don't know how to access this default style.

Comment: Luke, did you solve this problem? I'm a little bit confused by all those different ideas below. Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Yes, I used the answer below to get the template and modified it from there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For templates and styles that are not accessible through the Expression Interface (such as the ContextMenu template) you can use the following code to extract the template:

```
Dim sb As System.Text.StringBuilder = New System.Text.StringBuilder
Using Writer As TextWriter = New StringWriter(sb)
    System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(ContextMenu.Template, Writer)
End Using
Debug.Write(sb.ToString)
```

Or in C#

```
var str = new StringBuilder();
using (var writer = new StringWriter(str))
    XamlWriter.Save(ContextMenu.Template, writer);
Debug.Write(str);
```

Comment: Please note than in order to get a template in a ContextMenu you have to at least add one MenuItem to its Items collection. Otherwise the ContextMenu.Template is null.

Comment: I love Stack Overflow. Thanks so much for these responses, exactly what I needed too.

Comment: This is going to save me a ton of time. What a great tip.

Comment: I see what you did there.  Still, this is cool.  I'd upvote more if I could.

Answer (score 10):

I found the easy way to get the ContextMenu template in Blend:

1. I added a ContextMenu to a button with some menuitems.
2. Under "miscellaneous" in the properties pane, there's a grouped item for ContextMenu.
3. Open this. You'll find the usual Style and Template properties.
4. Click the square for the popup menu, and select Convert to New Resource...

That's it. Pick where you want the template/style to be put, and you're done.

Here's the markup I had:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Content="Click for ContextMenu" Width="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Template="{DynamicResource ContextMenuControlTemplate1}" Style="{DynamicResource ContextMenuStyle1}">
                <MenuItem Header="File"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
                <MenuItem Header="View"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Recent Files"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="file1.txt"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="file2.txt"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
</StackPanel>
```

And the style/template I got:

```
<Style x:Key="ContextMenuStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MenuBackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource WindowBorderBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Border Uid="Border_93">
                    <Border.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                            <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.DropShadowKey}}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,0,5,5"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Effect">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="4" Opacity="0.8" ShadowDepth="1"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Border.Style>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Hope this helps. In usual MS thoroughness, the brushes in the default style aren't found. :)

Comment: Ha ha!: *I found the easy way to get the ContextMenu template in Blend* - that sure looks like the easiest way!

Comment: Seems to be not a full XAML. Where is defining of 'ContextMenuControlTemplate1'?

Answer (score 4):

Try this: (Put this code in your Resources part of your XAML) This should remove the icon strip from the context menu.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Border BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="4" BorderBrush="Black" x:Name="Border" Background="White">
                    <StackPanel ClipToBounds="True" Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the space is not part of the ContextMenu it is part of MenuItem. So just drag a MenuItem to your window in expression blend and create a copy of the control. Hope your ContextMenu declaration is as follows

```
 <ContextMenu  >
    <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Clear"/>
 </ContextMenu>
```

And inside your MenuItem ControlTemplate you can see the space as bellow. So remove the Icon and First Column of the grid I marked in the screen shot.

[image]

Comment: Well that gets me the default style for the MenuItem, however it doesn't get me the ContextMenu style.  Expression Blend won't let me add a ContextMenu to the Window.

Comment: It shows an error, "ContextMenu cannot have logical or visual parent" if I add the ContextMenu to the window.

Comment: Yes, there is also styles within the ContextMenu for the left side menu that need to be removed.  It is the ContextMenu styles that I can't access using the Expression interface.  I have posted a solution below to extract the template using code.

Answer (score -1):

The extra space on the left is due to the little check mark that appears when you set `IsCheckable` and `IsChecked` to `true` on `MenuItem`.

The check mark is in the template for `MenuItem` so if you edit that you can take it out.

Comment: The `IsCheckable` property affects user interaction with a menu item, not whether the check/icon area is shown in the menu. In fact, the default value is already `False`. Setting it to `True` simply cases the checkmark to automatically toggle each time the user selects that menu item.