# How can I hide the space to the left of menu items in XAML menus?

Tags: wpf, xaml, menuitem

Is there a way that I can suppress the space to the left of a MenuItem's text?

[alt text http://tanguay.info/web/external/extraSpaceMenus.png](http://tanguay.info/web/external/extraSpaceMenus.png)

Something like `LeftAreaVisible="Collapsed"` (pseudo-code) below:

```
<Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
    <MenuItem 
        LeftAreaVisible="Collapsed"
        Header="MVVM" ItemsSource="{Binding MvvmMenuPageItemViewModels}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MainMenuTemplate}"/>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641634/default-contextmenu-style-wpf

Answer (score 0):

Struck through the somewhat same problem. Also did you noticed that there is no separator visible between Create Models and Create Pages. My issue was horizontal separator not completely visible i.e. for Highlighted area there is no horizontal separator.

[image]
Here is how i fixed it:

```
 <MenuItem Header="New"/>
            <Separator>
                <Separator.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Separator">
                        <Setter Property="Margin"
                                Value="0,3" />
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Separator}">
                                    <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding Border.BorderThickness}"
                                            Background="{StaticResource SeperatorBrush}" 
                                            Height="1" 
                                            SnapsToDevicePixels="true"/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Separator.Style>
            </Separator>
```

Also here is the brush.

```
 <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1" x:Key="SeperatorBrush">
        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
            <GradientStop Color="#FFF6F6F6" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFEAE8E8" Offset="0.25" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFDCD9D9" Offset="0.8" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
```

Brush is used to show the default appearance of Separator.