# ContextMenu: Remove the icon column and unnecessary space?

Tags: c#, wpf, contextmenu

I need to remove the icon column and the unnecessary space on the right side of a contextmenu. Here's a screenshot explaining it:

[alt text http://www.imagebanana.com/img/6j1g4896/contextmenu.png](http://www.imagebanana.com/img/6j1g4896/contextmenu.png)

Thanks for any hint!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default ContextMenu Style - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641634/default-contextmenu-style-wpf)

Comment: Even the accepted answer just refers to another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out: [Default ContextMenu Style - WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641634/default-contextmenu-style-wpf)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, looks complicated though ): Anyways, asking at the linked thread and marking this as answer.