# Styling ContextMenu and ContextMenu Items

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I am looking for a good example on styling ContextMenu and ContextMenu Items in WPF. What I would like is a breakdown of how ContextMenu, Menu, and MenuItems play together. From what I've found so far it seems like I can style part of them but not everything I want. A thorough example of styling each piece would be great or an article that walks through it would be even better.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default ContextMenu Style - WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641634/default-contextmenu-style-wpf)